# is it possible to use variable in Object Declaration in UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a command link below in `UFT/QTP`

```
Set oElement = oDUT.MNativeElement("by:=xpath","identifier:=" & vFinalProperty)
```

is it possible to assign `"oDUT.MNativeElement"` to a variable and execute the line.

Comment: What you have in **`oDUT`** ?

Comment: Set oDUT = Device("DUT")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this and then (as in your example) you would refer to `oElement` in the future when you needed to refer to it.  This is no different to defining a `Browser` object and referring to it later on.  If it's `Set` as an object reference it's fine.

For example:

```
oElement.Click ' will send a Click event (if available for this object type) to the oDUT.MNativeElement object
```

Comment: Sorry, My question is like strVariable="oDUT.MNativeElement".......            Set oElement = strVariable("by:=xpath","identifier:=" & vFinalProperty)

Comment: Never tried that - so I can't comment specifically on this use case.  But you could try looking up the `eval` command in vbscript (which is what UFT/QTP uses) and try using that...

Comment: i tried below sample using eval it is woking....!!!!   thanks...!!!                                                                 var="myxl"

srt=var&".Application.Visible = true"
srt1=var&".Workbooks.Add"

eval(srt)
eval(srt1)